# Stored procedure in Redshift to use string replacement with unload

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to achieve something among the following lines:

```
create or replace procedure my_sp_name(p_date date) as
$$
begin
    unload ('
    select *
    from my_table
    where my_date = ''DATE_GOES_HERE''
    ')
        to 's3://my-bucket/some_key/DATE_GOES_HERE/some_file'
        iam_role 'my_iam_role'
        allowoverwrite csv parallel off;
end ;
$$
    language plpgsql;
```

I have been trying different things, however, can't seem to find what is the correct way to to do the string replacement in both parts of the unload. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to EXECUTE "SQL statement" in the procedure.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html under "dynamic SQL" section.